# How can I change the font size options in Microsoft Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

How can I change the font size options in Microsoft Visio 2013?

E.g., I would like to add 20 pt.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply write 20pt and press Enter in cascade menu. In the other Microsoft Office  suite programs, it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, I meant I want to add the `20pt` option in the drop-down menu.